# Can I decrypt a gpg encrypted file on any computer?

Tags: security, encryption, gnupg, internet-security

I am storing some 2FA recovery keys inside a txt file, which I then encrypted using `gpg -c file`, I can decrypt it fine in my own computer (virtual machine actually).

But I was wondering, if something happens to my virtual machine, can I still decrypt the file on any other computer? Or do I need to export some private key or something like that to be able to do it?

Comment: You would need the key used to encrypt the file.